# SSH with Command and File in Java

Tags: java, ssh, jsch, sshj

I'd like to run SSH within Java but I haven't figured out how to run an SSH statement that includes a command and file.  The command for example in a standard terminal:

```
ssh user@host 'upload' < myfile.txt
```

Hopefully via a Java library, not some type of Runtime.exec()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:
http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Here you have the example you need:
http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ScpTo.java.html